# Tall red piece with coffee cup, phone and gas picture?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I have a few of these taller red pieces with logos of gas, phone, and a coffee cup on them. I've been searching online for days and cannot find a gas station, store, or anything with these pieces in it. Can you help me identify the set this came in?

[image]

Answer (score 15):

This brick comes from set [6393: Big Rig Truck Stop](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6393-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from 1987.

[image]

The official BrickLink name of this brick is [3755pb01 Brick 1 x 3 x 5 with Cup, Phone, and Water Tap Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3755pb01&name=Brick%201%20x%203%20x%205%20with%20Cup,%20Phone,%20and%20Water%20Tap%20Pattern&category=%5BBrick,%20Decorated%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

Comment: Were these pre-printed parts?  The pictures look like it is done with a sticker.

Comment: Nope, these are printed parts. There is a sticker sheet for this set, but it only contains the striping for the window panes (simulating blinds).